# How do I get the url string to a django view?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, django-forms

I don't know if i'm doing this the right way, but in my django application I have javascript helping out the login page. I made an ajax rest api on my django server (with that whole csrv authentication).

Now, I want to redirect the user when the javascript successfully posts an ajax call to the server. I figured it might be easy to return a json with a 'success': true and a 'url': , but I can't figure out a nice way to get that url string. I know django is strict on only typing out the url in one spot and referencing it from the urls.py.

My question is: How do I get that url string to send to the client-side? OR if there is a better way to do this, how do I go about that?

(The reason I'm not using forms is because I need to filter out certain signup things that I cannot filter from the usual way of putting {{ LoginForm }} into the template)

Comment: What is this url? Is it fixed or somewhat dynamic?

Comment: If you simply want to redirect why aren't you using HttpResponseRedirect?

Comment: I'm not redirecting because I'm using a jquery ajax call to get the information. I don't think a HttpResponseRedirect will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse) function

`reverse('url-name')` will return the path to your view named url-name